# How do you add a new view controller to a container with the same characteristics as the parent?

Tags: ios, swift

So, hopefully someone may be familiar with this guide on how to create a slide out side bar menu

http://www.raywenderlich.com/78568/create-slide-out-navigation-panel-swift#comments

Ive followed this guide and would like to create an app like Venmo or groupme. Where there side navigation panel is used as a menu and when a cell is tapped, it segues to a new view controller with the same nav bar on top as the parent controller.

What would be the right way about going about this?

Here is my container code
centerview is the initial view controller with the "home page" i guess
sidepanel is the slide out menu as a tableview.

i would like to create a new VC lets call it newViewController and when i click a cell in the sidepanel, it segues to newViewController which has the same navbar and functionality as the centerview but with different content obviously.

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

enum SlideOutState {
    case BothCollapsed
    case LeftPanelExpanded
    case RightPanelExpanded
}





let centerPanelExpandedOffset: CGFloat = 80


class ContainerViewController: UIViewController, CenterViewControllerDelegate {

    var currentState: SlideOutState = .BothCollapsed
    var leftViewController: SidePanelViewController?
    var centerNavigationController: UINavigationController!
    var centerViewController: CenterViewController!
    var browseFlavorNavigationController: UINavigationController!
    var browseFlavorViewController: CenterViewController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        centerViewController = UIStoryboard.centerViewController()
        centerViewController.delegate = self

        // wrap the centerViewController in a navigation controller, so we can push views to it
        // and display bar button items in the navigation bar
        centerNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: centerViewController)
        view.addSubview(centerNavigationController.view)
        addChildViewController(centerNavigationController)

        centerNavigationController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    }

    // MARK: CenterViewController delegate methods

    func toggleLeftPanel() {

        let notAlreadyExpanded = (currentState != .LeftPanelExpanded)

        if notAlreadyExpanded {
            addLeftPanelViewController()
        }

        animateLeftPanel(shouldExpand: notAlreadyExpanded)
    }

    func collapseSidePanels() {
        switch (currentState) {
        case .LeftPanelExpanded:
            toggleLeftPanel()
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    func addLeftPanelViewController() {

        if (leftViewController == nil) {
            leftViewController = UIStoryboard.leftViewController()
            leftViewController!.navigation = Settings.allSettings()

            addChildSidePanelController(leftViewController!)
        }
    }
    func addChildSidePanelController(sidePanelController: SidePanelViewController) {
        view.insertSubview(sidePanelController.view, atIndex: 0)

        addChildViewController(sidePanelController)
        sidePanelController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    }

    func addRightPanelViewController() {
    }

    func animateLeftPanel(#shouldExpand: Bool) {
        if (shouldExpand) {
            currentState = .LeftPanelExpanded

            animateCenterPanelXPosition(targetPosition: CGRectGetWidth(centerNavigationController.view.frame) - centerPanelExpandedOffset)
        } else {
            animateCenterPanelXPosition(targetPosition: 0) { finished in
                self.currentState = .BothCollapsed

                self.leftViewController!.view.removeFromSuperview()
                self.leftViewController = nil;
            }
        }
    }

    func animateCenterPanelXPosition(#targetPosition: CGFloat, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)! = nil) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.centerNavigationController.view.frame.origin.x = targetPosition
            }, completion: completion)
    }


    func animateRightPanel(#shouldExpand: Bool) {
    }

    // MARK: Gesture recognizer

    func handlePanGesture(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    }
}

private extension UIStoryboard {
  class func mainStoryboard() -> UIStoryboard { return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()) }

  class func leftViewController() -> SidePanelViewController? {
    return mainStoryboard().instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LeftViewController") as? SidePanelViewController
  }

  class func rightViewController() -> SidePanelViewController? {
    return mainStoryboard().instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RightViewController") as? SidePanelViewController
  }

  class func centerViewController() -> CenterViewController? {
    return mainStoryboard().instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CenterViewController") as? CenterViewController
  }
}
```